# How to pad numbers with variable substitution for padding width in format or f string?

Tags: python

I want to pad a number `i` with a padding based on the value of the variable `width`

```py
>>> width = 5
>>> i = 1
>>> print(f'{i:width}')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Invalid format specifier
>>>
>>> print('{:width}'.format(i))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Invalid format specifier
```

Desired output:

```
1
```

Comment: [Parametrized formats](https://pyformat.info/#param_align)

Comment: @Tomerikoo do you know of any updated versions of that covering f-strings?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Not specifically, but I believe it mostly covers it (assuming some very basic understanding of the syntaxes). Anyway, it is possible to contribute to that site [through GitHub](https://github.com/ulope/pyformat.info) apparently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
>>> width = 5
>>> i = 1
>>> print(f'{i:{width}}')
    1
```